# { int == nulltype } vs. { Integer == nulltype }

Tags: java, comparison, int

Why java complains about

```
// int i;
if( i == null ){  }
```

and not about

```
// Integer i;
if( i == null ){  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because Integer is a reference type, and an `int` is not - that is, as `int` is not a pointer, it cannot point to nothing.

Answer (score 2):

int (primitive type) can't be null

Answer (score 1):

Because `int` is a primitive type , while `Integer` is its wrapper class .

Said differently, `int` is a *value type* (and as such cannot be `null`) while `Integer` is a *reference type* (and as such can be `null`).

In Java, every primitive type (such as `boolean`, `double` or `char`) is a value type. Since primitive types do not inherit from `Object`, a set of "wrapper classes" is offered (`Boolean`, `Double`, `Character` to name a few) when such behavior is needed (like, for instance, putting them in containers, or using them as generic type parameters).

The result is that primitive types really are second class citizens in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Because int is a value type and it cannot be null - it's the object itself. Integer, on the other hand, is a reference type and can be null or hold a reference to an object.